# Point Of Sales - Stuck on arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object

Basically I have multiple classes and I'm trying to get an array of LineItem for each Item that a customer purchases. LineItem includes the UPC, Description, Price, Quantity, SubTotal and Discount which is all stored in a seperate class. I'm trying to get it that when you use the method addItemToSaleList it will add to the array. I need to use an array and not an array list, so I have to copy over the array to a temp array, and then recreate a new array adding to the number the array can store and then recopying it over. I'm stuck getting the array to generate. Below is the code I have

```
public class Product {
private double price;
private String description;
private String ProductCode;
private DiscountStrategy discoutStrategy;

public Product(double price, String description, String ProductCode, DiscountStrategy discoutStrategy) {
    this.price = price;
    this.description = description;
    this.ProductCode = ProductCode;
    this.discoutStrategy = discoutStrategy;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getProductCode() {
    return ProductCode;
}

public void setProductCode(String ProductCode) {
    this.ProductCode = ProductCode;
}

public DiscountStrategy getDiscountStrategy() {
    return discoutStrategy;
}

public void setDiscoutStrategy(DiscountStrategy discoutStrategy) {
    this.discoutStrategy = discoutStrategy;
}
}


public class LineItem {
private Product product;
private double quantity;

public LineItem(Product product, double quantity) {
    this.product = product;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

//Calculates the Discount Amount whether or not it's a percentage or dollar
//off
public double getDiscountAmount () {
    return product.getDiscountStrategy().getDiscount(product.getPrice(), quantity);
}

//Calculates the Subtotal, gets the quantity from the DiscountStrategy and then
//the price from the product
public double getSubTotal() {
    return quantity * product.getPrice();
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

 public double getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(double quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}



public class Receipt {
private LineItem[] lineItem = new LineItem[0];

public Receipt(LineItem[] lineItem) {
    this.lineItem = lineItem;
}


public void addProductToTotalSale(LineItem li) {
    addItemToSaleList();
}

public void addItemToSaleList() {
   LineItem[] tempItemList = new LineItem[lineItem.length + 1];

   for (int i = 0; i < tempItemList.length; i++) {
       tempItemList[i] = lineItem[i];
   }

   lineItem = new LineItem[tempItemList.length];

   for (int j = 0; j < lineItem.length; j++) {
       lineItem[j] = tempItemList[j];
   }
}

public LineItem[] getLineItem() {
    return lineItem;
}
```

Comment: I only skimmed over your question but from your description you may want to consider using an `ArrayList` since `Arrays` are fixed length and you can append to the end of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Why can't you use an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Requirement for the project requires me to use an array. It's for my java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are making two new arrays.  You only need one...

```
public void addProductToTotalSale(LineItem li) {
    addItemToSaleList();
    lineItem[lineItem.length-1] = li;
}

public void addItemToSaleList() {
   LineItem[] tempItemList = new LineItem[lineItem.length + 1];

   for (int i = 0; i < tempItemList.length; i++) {
     tempItemList[i] = lineItem[i];
   }
   lineItem = tempItemList;
}
```

Comment: the first array lineItem does not have a length, and every time a customer adds a new product the array will increase. That's why I had two arrays, but I see there is a short cut with your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove `addItemToSaleList()` and implement `addProductToTotalSale(LineItem)` like so

```
public void addProductToTotalSale(LineItem li) {
  // Allocate the memory.
  LineItem[] tempLineItem = new LineItem[1 + lineItem.length];
  // Copy the array.
  if (lineItem.length > 0) {
    System.arraycopy(lineItem, 0, tempLineItem, 0, lineItem.length);
  }
  // add the new item to the new slot.
  tempLineItem[lineItem.length] = li;
  // update the internal array reference.
  lineItem = tempLineItem;
}
```

Next, you should protect your constructor from `null`;

```
public Receipt(LineItem[] lineItem) {
  // Try and protect from bad calls, removes need to check for nulls in
  // add (addProductToTotalSale) routine.
  if (lineItem != null) {
    this.lineItem = lineItem;
  }
}
```

Because you provide a default `0` sized array your code appears to be safe to continue to include the default constructor. But, you might consider making your `Receipt` class immutable.